# Permitted composition of lithium oxometallate in lithium-ion battery and its influence on ion transfer

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, transition-metals, alkali-metals

The following scheme describes the overall reaction that takes place in a Li-ion battery:

$$
\begin{align}
\ce{Li_{$y$}C6 &-> $y$ Li+ + $y$ e- + C6} &\quad &\text{(anode)} \tag{R1}\\
\ce{Li_{$1-y$}MO2 + $y$ Li+ + $y$ e- &-> LiMO2} &\quad &\text{(cathode)} \tag{R2}\\
\hline
\ce{Li_{$y$}C6 + Li_{$1-y$}MO2 &-> LiMO2 + C6} \tag{R3}
\end{align}
$$

However, I'm confused by the $1-y$ subscript in the lithium oxometallate. While the formula makes sense for $y=1$ $(1 - 1 = 0),$ if $y=2,$ wouldn't the subscript for $\ce{Li}$ be negative?

What would this physically correspond to in terms of lithium ion transfer?

Comment: Note that "y" in $\ce{Li_{y}CoO2}$ must not reach anywhere close to 1 nor 0, as for 1 it tends to irreversibly separate to Li2O and Co2O3 oxides, for 0 CoO2 tends to release oxygen.

Comment: @Poutnik I was under the impression that the y referred to the number of Li+ ions that were transferred in the reaction. What does it actually represent?

Comment: y does not have fixed meaning. In my case it means non stoichiometric lithium coefficient in Li_yCoO2. I could have used x instead. I apologize for confusion.

Comment: Apparently the source you've borrowed the scheme from didn't mention $y\in[0;1]$ (well, they sorta did by using $1-y$ in place of plain $y$). The second question about the influence of $y$ on ion transfer doesn't appear that trivial though, +1 for that.

Comment: It is common that some mathematical expressions have physical sense just in some value intervals. The typical cases are solutions of a quadratic equation with one of the roots negative. In your case it is $0 \lt y \lt 1$, so does  $0 \lt x \lt 1$ for $\ce{Li_{x}MO2}$, as these materials within the cell operation context are kept avoiding stoichiometric composition. In context of this, your second question is unclear.